# checking if condition for 0 value

Tags: php

in if condition i want to check

```
if(isset($_GET['q']))
{
 echo "ok";
}
esle
{
 echo "not ok";
}
```

when $_GET['q']=0 if send me in else part.

But i want to go in if .

if $_GET['q']  have any value even for  0 if should print ok

any help pls ?

Comment: That should not be the case. Among "set" variables only `null` values count as "not set", `0` should definitely "be set". Try a `var_dump($_GET['q'])`.

Comment: aside form the typos you have here (which arent the problem cause they would give you syntax errors) that should work. Are you sure that `$_GET['q']` is actually `0`... its not in `$_POST` or passed as `$_GET['Q']`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what `isset` does. Try:

```
$x["q"] = 0;
var_dump(isset($x["q"]));
```

You will get true. If you think `isset()` returns `false` on `0` you are looking at the wrong place, look for a bug elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

0 is not null http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

You might need something like this considering the value you want is integer

```
if(isset($_GET['q']) && intval($_GET['q']) > 0 )
{
 echo "ok";
}
else
{
 echo "not ok";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

perhaps `array_key_exists()` would be more appropriate.

`if ( array_key_exists( 'q', $_GET ) ) ...`

Comment: A `$_GET` value can only be "not set" at all or have a value other than `null`. As such, using `array_key_exists` and `isset` should yield identical results.

Comment: Not sure precisely what you mean in the first sentence. But I did a quick test and as far as I can tell, you are correct in the second sentence. I think op may have some weird stuff going on (or an error) as @prodigitalson suggests.

Comment: First sentence: `foo.php?` → `$_GET['q']` is *not set*, `foo.php?q` → `$_GET['q'] === ''`. The value is either *not set*, or has some value. It can never be `null`. As such, `isset` and `array_key_exists` make no difference.

Comment: ah, okay, that's what I though. I just wasn't sure from the wording.

Comment: It's not easy to express things in an accurate *and* understandable way in only 600 characters... ;o)

Answer (score 0):

I think this  is the correct one...

```
if(array_key_exists('q', $_GET)){
   echo "ok";
}
else{
    echo "not ok";
}
```